# Modified egg dropping puzzle

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Suppose that I have *m* eggs and wish to know which floors in a *n*-floor (n>=2) building are safe to drop eggs from, and which will cause the eggs to break on landing.

There is few assumptions:

1. An egg that survives a fall stays on first floor and can be used again. I have to go down on first floor to collect survived eggs.
2. A broken egg can't be used again.
3. The effect of a fall is the same for all eggs.
4. If an egg breaks when dropped, then it would break if dropped from a higher window.
5. If an egg survives a fall, then it would survive a shorter fall.
6. Eggs breaks when dropped from highest floor, and doesn't break when dropped from first floor.

It is hard for me to go up by stairs, and easy to go down.

How do I minimize distance for traveling on higher floors?

Comment: Minimize what? Worst case, average case, something else?

Comment: Minimize distance in worst case.

Comment: It seems like you can parameterize the problem by: the number of unbroken dropped eggs, the number of eggs you hold, the floor you're currently on, the highest floor you know is safe, and the lowest floor you know is unsafe. Then use DP.

Comment: @PaulHankin There is no need to DP. It is pure math.

Comment: @user58697 I would be interested in seeing a purely mathematical solution for this problem. Do you have a writeup somewhere?

Comment: @PaulHankin It is sort of trivial for a writeup. The trick is to solve a very similar problem, namely, how tall building can be inspected with no more than `k` drops. For two eggs, you can easily see that you shall start at floor `k`, and if an egg survives, proceed `k-1` floor up, etc. Summing the progression gives `k(k-1)/2` floors. It is trivially generalized for more eggs. Now given the height of the building, solve the resulting equation for `k`.

Comment: @user58697 how do you go from the usual egg-dropping problem (which I think you're solving here) to minimizing the number of floors climbed? I suppose it's trivial to you, but I don't see it.

Comment: @PaulHankin Oh, I misread the question indeed, sorry. However the same logic applies - how tall a tower you can inspect being limited by a total climb. It is still polynomial. There is a (not so) truly remarkable proof which the comment space is nevertheless too small to contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution on Haskell for general traveled distance [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-minimize-the-distance-traveled-in-the-two-egg-problem), then rewrote it on Python and modified for my task.

```py
from math import inf
from collections import namedtuple
from functools import lru_cache

Solution = namedtuple('Solution', ('moves', 'floors'))


@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def solve(held, dropped, height, lo, hi):
    if hi == lo + 1:
        return Solution(0, [])
    solutions = list()
    if dropped:
        moves, floors = solve(held + dropped, 0, 1, lo, hi)
        solutions.append(Solution(moves, [1] + floors))
    if held:
        for _height in range(lo + 1, hi):
            breaks = solve(held - 1, dropped, _height, lo, _height)
            survives = solve(held - 1, dropped + 1, _height, _height, hi)
            worst = max((breaks, survives), key=lambda x: x.moves)
            solutions.append(
                Solution(
                    max(_height - height, 0) + worst.moves,
                    [_height] + worst.floors
                )
            )
    return min(solutions, key=lambda x: x.moves, default=Solution(inf, []))


print(solve(3, 0, 1, 1, 100))
```